# Обновление ListView при нажатии назад

Tags: android

Добрый день. Использую ListView для реализации файлового менеджера. Хотелось бы, чтобы при нажатии кнопки назад отображалась родительская папка данной папки. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
//startPath, currentPath - строки
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_chooser);

    final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.filesList);
    adapter = new mAdapter(this, getFiles(currentPath));
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String tmpPath = ((File) lv.getItemAtPosition(position)).getPath();
            if(position == 0 ) {
                if(!currentPath.equals(startPath))
                {
                    currentPath = new File(currentPath).getParent();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                currentPath = tmpPath;
            }
            if (new File(currentPath).isFile()) {

                sendPath();
                Log.d(TAG, "choose file");
                return;
            }
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.addAll(getFiles(currentPath));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });}

ArrayList<File> getFiles(String path)
{
    File dir = new File(path);
    File[] result = dir.listFiles();
    ArrayList<File> res =  new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(result));
    res.add(0, new File(currentPath));
    return res;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(!currentPath.equals(startPath))
        currentPath = new File(currentPath).getParent();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


private class mAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<File>{

    private boolean multiswitch = false;
     void enableMultiSwitch()
     {
         multiswitch = true;
     }
    void disableMultiSwitch()
    {
        multiswitch = false;
    }


    int i = 0;
    public mAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<File> files) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_item_list, files);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.d(TAG, i++ +"");
        if(multiswitch)
        {
            if(convertView != null)
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.multi_item_list, null);
        }else{
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item_list, null);
            }
        }



        View      view = convertView;
        TextView  tView;
        ImageView iView;
        CheckBox  chBox = null;

        if(!multiswitch) {
            tView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.singleItemFileName);
            iView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.singleItemImageView);
        }
        else{
            tView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.multiItemFileName);
            iView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.multiItemImageView);
            chBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.multiItemCheckBox);
        }


        File file = getItem(position);

            tView.setText(file.getName());
            if(chBox != null)
                chBox.setChecked(false);

            /*if(!file.isFile())
                iView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_folder_black_48dp);
            else
                iView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_description_black_48dp);*/

        return view;
    }


}
```

Но таким образом ничего не происходит. Как можно обновить ListView. Использую свой ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Нам неизвестно что у вас в адаптере и должен ли он у вас поменяться в таком случае.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет, адаптер из-за этого мне меняется никак, просто думал,что произойдет перестройка ListView

Comment: Не видно никакого кода. Магически ничего не поменяется. Список должен подчиняться некоей логике, завязанной на путь к папке. Этой логики в вопросе нет. Как вам помочь если ничего вы не говорите?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил код. Просто хочу узнать, есть ли встроенная перестройка ListView

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "встроенная перестройка"?.. А вообще, вам, вроде, надо лишь добавить обновление данных в адаптере `adapter.clear();
            adapter.addAll(getFiles(currentPath));`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй ListView.notifyDataSetChanged() встроенный метод.